# Why isn't my Meta_Query running?

Tags: wp-query

Just FYI, I'm not an experienced coder, and I have had very little experience with coding PHP, it's safe to say I don't know the basics, just what I am teaching myself along the way to read and understand and then edit existing code.

I have a site with a purchased Theme which includes a custom tax_query which I've copied the structure of to try and filter queries by different fields in the Meta data. I'm placing my function in the functions.php file within my Child theme which contains all my modifications so far.

Here is my code:

```
function ah_meta_queries( $query = false ) {
    if ( ! ( is_post_type_archive( 'listing' ) || is_tax( 'listing_type' ) || is_tax( 'listing_location' ) ) ) return;

    if ( is_admin() || ! is_a( $query, 'WP_Query' ) || ! $query->is_main_query() ) return;

    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'listing' ) ) {
        $meta_query_args = array( 'relation' => 'AND' );

        // For each type of Meta Data, check if filtering is set, then add it to the query array

        if ( isset( $_GET['et-listing-rating'] ) && 'none' != $_GET['et-listing-rating'] ) {
        $meta_query_args[] = array(
                'key' => 'listing_type',
                'value' =>  intval( $_GET['et-listing-rating'] ),
        ); }

        if ( isset( $_GET['Fitness'] ) )
        $meta_query_args[] = array(
                'key' => 'HN_Fitness',
                'value' => 'TRUE',
        );

        if ( isset( $_GET['Furnished'] ) ) 
        $meta_query_args[] = array(
                'key' => 'HN_Furnished',
                'value' => 'TRUE',
        );

        if ( isset( $_GET['Kitchen'] ) ) 
        $meta_query_args[] = array(
                'key' => 'HN_Kitchen', 
                'value' => 'TRUE',
        );

        if ( isset( $_GET['Parking'] ) ) 
        $meta_query_args[] = array(
                'key' => 'HN_Parking',
                'value' => 'TRUE',
        );

        if ( isset( $_GET['Pets Allowed'] ) ) 
        $meta_query_args[] = array(
                'key' => 'HN_Pets',
                'value' => 'TRUE',
        );

        if ( isset( $_GET['Pool'] ) )
        $meta_query_args[] = array(
                'key' => 'HN_Pool',
                'value' => 'TRUE',
        );          

        // If user input Price-Low but no Price-High, make sure Listing Price Low or Listing Price High is more than Price-Low
        if ( (isset( $_GET['price-low'] ) && '' !=$_GET['price-low'] ) && !isset( $_GET['price-high']) )
        $meta_query_args[] = array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(  
                    'key' => 'HN_Price_Low',
                    'value' => $_GET['price-low'],
                    'type' => 'numeric',
                    'compare' => '>=', 
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'HN_Price_High',
                    'value' => $_GET['price-low'],
                    'type' => 'numeric',
                    'compare' => '>=',
                ),
        );

        // If user input Price-High but no Price-Low, make sure Listing Price Low or Listing Price High is less than Price-High
        if ( !isset( $_GET['price-low']) && (isset( $_GET['price-high'] ) && '' !=$_GET['price-high'] ) )
        $meta_query_args[] = array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(  
                    'key' => 'HN_Price_Low',
                    'value' => $_GET['price-high'],
                    'type' => 'numeric',
                    'compare' => '<=', 
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'HN_Price_High',
                    'value' => $_GET['price-high'],
                    'type' => 'numeric',
                    'compare' => '<=',
                ),
        );

        // If user input both Price-Low AND Price-High, make sure Listing Price Low or Listing Price High is BETWEEN Price-Low and Price-High
        if ( (isset( $_GET['price-low'] ) && '' !=$_GET['price-low'] ) && (isset( $_GET['price-high'] ) && '' !=$_GET['price-high'] ) )
        $meta_query_args[] = array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(  
                    'key' => 'HN_Price_Low',
                    'value' => array( $_GET['price-low'], $_GET['price-high'] ),
                    'type' => 'numeric',
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN', 
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'HN_Price_High',
                    'value' => array( $_GET['price-low'], $_GET['price-high'] ),
                    'type' => 'numeric',
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                ),
        );



        // If any of the filters are set in the URL, then run the Meta Query

        if (    ( isset( $_GET['et-listing-rating'] ) && 'none' != $_GET['et-listing-rating'] ) ||
                isset( $_GET['Fitness'] ) ||
                isset( $_GET['Furnished'] ) ||
                isset( $_GET['Kitchen'] ) ||
                isset( $_GET['Parking'] ) ||
                isset( $_GET['Pets Allowed'] ) ||       
                isset( $_GET['Pool'] ) ||       
                ( isset( $_GET['price-low'] ) && '' !=$_GET['price-low'] ) ||
                ( isset( $_GET['price-high']) && '' !=$_GET['price-high'] )
            )
            $meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query_args );            

    }
}
```

Some of the questions I have are: 
-why isnt this running? do I have to set the function to run anywhere else?
-why is the function declared with the argument ( $query = false ) ?

Any suggestions are very welcome!!

Comment: Are you calling this function anywhere? Have you assigned it as a filter to some hook? (Which one?)

Comment: No, I'm not sure how where to call the function??

Couldn't find where to call the function from anywhere in the documentation about functions.php and since I'm so new to all this... 

Haha sorry to be so hopeless.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't assigned it to any hook and you don't call it, then it can't work - this function is never called.

You should assign it to `pre_get_posts` hook, I guess (at least it looks so).

Add this after your function:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'ah_meta_queries' );
```

It should work fine then.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your suggestion. I've added that into the functions.php of my child theme and it still seems not to be working.

Perhaps, it's my syntax?